# function that modifies object pointed to by std::unique_ptr<T>

Tags: c++11, move, unique-ptr

Somewhere in my code I have a local `std::unique_ptr<T>`. I need to do stuff with the object pointed at, and I use a function for that:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> some_function( std::unique_ptr<T> &t )
{
    // do stuff
    return t;
}
```

I call the function like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> some_T_ptr( new T(/*args*/) );
vector_of_finalized_Ts.push_back( std::move(some_function(std::move(some_T_ptr))));
```

Now I wonder, is there a better way to get the necessary functionality? It just seems two moves are pretty superfluous and potentially dangerous. I do have error handling code I'm not showing here, but that's beside the point.

Comment: `T some_T = new T(/*args*/);` is not valid C++.

Comment: Your code shows an rvalue being passed to `some_function` but `some_function` takes its argument by non-const lvalue reference.  This code isn't valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is all about ownership.  Do you want `some_function` to take ownership of the pointer or not?  If not, you can just pass a raw pointer to `some_function`.  If you want `some_function` to take ownership (and return ownership), then it should take the `unique_ptr` by value.  Otherwise the return statement (which should be `std::move(t)`) will be moving from a reference of unknown origins.

```
std::unique_ptr<T> some_function( std::unique_ptr<T> t )
{
    // I own t here and will delete it if an exception happens
    // do stuff
    // I'm transferring ownership back to the caller
    //     (who may or may not accept ownership)
    return std::move(t);
}

vector_of_finalized_Ts.push_back( some_function(std::move(some_T_ptr)));
```

or:

```
void some_function( T* t )
{
    // I don't own t and won't delete it if an exception happens
    // do stuff
}

some_function(some_T_ptr.get());
vector_of_finalized_Ts.push_back( std::move(some_T_ptr));
```

Either design is fine.  It just depends on what code should own the pointer (especially if an exception is thrown at some point).

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(Ignoring the unrelated syntax error in your code. See my comment above for that.)</sup>

As far as your snippet goes, your code is valid. The verbosity of the moves is the price you pay for using `std::unique_ptr` in this manner, and for passing the `unique_ptr` into the function rather than a reference to the object itself.

I suppose you have your good reasons for wanting `some_function` to take a `std::unique_ptr` and, if that's the case, then as far as I can tell you can't really do any better.

If you *don't* have your good reasons then, well, there's your answer. :)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you both take the `unique_ptr` by reference *and* return it. It's a unique pointer- you're treating it liked a shared pointer, and you're left with a wasted `nullptr` value on the stack. If you took it by value or by rvalue reference, you could just call some_function directly, and you don't have to move the result.

```
std::unique_ptr<T> some_function( std::unique_ptr<T> &&t )
{
    // do stuff
    return t;
}
vector_of_finalized_Ts.push_back( some_function(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(...))));
```